# Using Flask-OpenID in App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I am trying out Flask-OpenID in App Engine. Flask-OpenID uses a 'store' to save authentication information. If I mention '/some/path' to save data, it doesn't work in App Engine, as it is read-only.

For Flask-OpenID to work, I have to write my own 'store' which uses App Engine's datastore or cloud storage. I have not much idea on how to write this store. Is there any document available, so that I can follow. It will be helpful if I get any input on writing the 'store' using Flask and App Engine.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am **not** the author of the framework, but I am using it everyday. You can start with [gae-init](http://gae-init.appspot.com) which is a working example using [Flask-OAuth](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-OAuth/) for authentication. Login and other goodies are provided out of the box, and you can get an overview about it and educate yourself at [docs](http://docs.gae-init.appspot.com) which are still under construction.

Comment: Did you try Flask-OAuth in app engine?

Comment: [gae-init](http://gae-init.appspot.com) authentication mechanism is using Flask-OAuth, so I guess the answer is yes, unless I got your question wrong :), and you can find the implementation under `gae-init/main/src/auth.py`

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried Flask-OAuth yet.I will do it when I get time.
BTW, If you are interested on my issue, refer [here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-openid/issues/16)